# Como faço uma gravação de navegação em javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá,
Estamos desenvolvendo um sistema no qual o cliente quer implementar um sistema de gravação de navegação, para seus clientes.
Na intenção de monitoria interna da plataforma.
Ou seja os clientes deles analisarem seus funcionários.
Assim como alguns de sites se propõem pela internet como é o caso do:

[Inspectlet](https://www.inspectlet.com/)

[Smartlook](https://www.smartlook.com/pt/)

Porém precisa ser implementado em ambiente com internet fechada. Impossibilitando o uso dos citados a cima.

Alguém conhece algum projeto desde tipo? Se sim, como cria-lo em javascript / jQuery?

Comment: 1º Para criar um projeto desse na mão, não é nada rápido/fácil.
2º Creio que para criar um sistema desse, apenas `jquery` não é o suficiente, seria necessário usar algo na parte do `back-end`, talvez o `node.js`

Comment: Temos conhecimento disto, porém não achamos nada na internet que pudesse dar um start no projeto. Ou seja um luz de como fazer isso sem precisar mexer no navegador da pessoa. Assim como os links a cima fazem. Entramos em contato inclusive com a empresa citadas a cima e as mesmas informaram que não fazer offline o serviço que foi na intenção de não precisar desenvolver. Estamos atras de um projeto github da vida que alguem ja tenha iniciado algo parecido.

Comment: Olá, Encontramos um solução para o que precisamos no github. Quem quiser segue link do projeto: [https://github.com/hmert/jquery-event-playback](https://github.com/hmert/jquery-event-playback)